# CSS transition image from black white to color

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've seen many websites that have a black and white image that transitions to a colored version with a `:hover` selector. What I'm trying to do is the same but with no user interaction. For example, the image would start black and white and fade to its colored version after 10 seconds.

Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Like this?

```css
@keyframes toColor {
    0%    { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%); }
    25%   { -webkit-filter: grayscale(75%); filter: grayscale(75%); }
    50%   { -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%); filter: grayscale(50%); }
    75%   { -webkit-filter: grayscale(25%); filter: grayscale(25%); }
    100%  { -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); filter: grayscale(0%); }
}


img.desaturate { 
   animation: toColor 10s;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gMPdDHk.jpg" alt="Lena Söderberg" style="width: 300px;" class="desaturate">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to use rollOver behavior in order to launch the image colorization animation on image hover.

```
img{ filter: grayscale(100%); transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;}
img:hover { filter: none;}
```